# MySQL SELECT from multiple tables, multiple GROUP BY and group_concat?

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I have three tables which I want to query in MySQ. As follows:

```
**Table: Leaderboard**
Name  | Score
------------
James | 1
Steve | 2
Dave  | 5

**Table: Actions**
Name  | Action       | Time
----------------------------
James | Ate an apple | 01:00
James | Kicked a dog | 02:00
Steve | Ate a dog    | 03:00
Steve | Kicked a hen | 01:00
Dave  | died         | 02:00

**Table: Items**
Name  | Item         | Time
----------------------------
James | Chainsaw     | 01:00
James | Hammer       | 01:05
James | Crowbar      | 01:10
Steve | Hammer       | 02:00
Steve | Egg          | 01:05
Dave  | Egg          | 01:05
```

I need a query which selects each player (ORDER BY Leaderboard.score DESC) and selects their latest Action WHERE Actions.action LIKE 'Ate %', and then gives all Items.Item ORDER BY Time DESC

So for example, the output would look like this

```
**Output**
Name   | Latest_Action | Items
Steve  | Ate a dog     | Hammer, Egg
James  | Ate an apple  | Crowbar, Hammer, Chainsaw
```

So far I have tried the following query but it returns each Item multiple times in the group_concat

```
SELECT Leaderboard.Name, Actions.*, group_concat(Items.Item)
FROM Leaderboard, Actions, Items
WHERE Items.Name = Actions.Name
  AND Actions.Action LIKE 'Ate %'
  AND Actions.Name IN (SELECT Name FROM Leaderboard ORDER BY SCORE DESC)
GROUP BY Leaderboard.name
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Your use of the subquery to sort the result won't work: the outer `GROUP BY` will override any sorting present so far.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT Leaderboard.Name,
  (SELECT Actions.Action
   FROM Actions
   WHERE Actions.Name = Leaderboard.Name
     AND Actions.Action LIKE 'Ate%'
   ORDER BY Time DESC
   LIMIT 1
  ) AS Latest_Action,
  GROUP_CONCAT(Items.Item
               ORDER BY Items.Time DESC
               SEPARATOR ', '
              ) AS Items
FROM Leaderboard
     LEFT JOIN Items ON Leaderboard.Name = Items.Name
GROUP BY Leaderboard.Name
HAVING Latest_Action IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY Leaderboard.Score DESC
```

Result verified in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11255/5/0).

Comment: Make that: `GROUP_CONCAT(Items.Item SEPARATOR ', ' ORDER BY Items.Time DESC)`

Comment: @ypercube: Thanks, missed that part.

Comment: This works exactly as requested, many thanks.
How would I select multiple columns from the Actions table?

Comment: @user1491032: Discussing this question would exceed the scope of such comment, particularly in terms of source code formatting capabilities. Beter ask a subsequent question about this.